# Erro Wordpress com apply_filters() no load.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Galera, estou com esse erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in
>   /var/www/html/lojadec.com.br/web/blog/wp-includes/load.php on line
>   316.

Não sei o que fazer!

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro e o arquivo onde ela acontece só dá pra saber que tem alguma coisa não carregando corretamente na ordem dos arquivos do WordPress. Você tem mais detalhes? Fez alguma modificação recente no site? Mudou de hospedagem? Uma coisa simples que pode ser feita é baixar a versão mais recente aqui: https://br.wordpress.org/ e substituir todos os arquivos na hospedagem, exceto a pasta `wp-content`.

Comment: Bem... como nãohavia conseguido uma resposta a curto prazo do cliente, resolvi fazer a migração manualmente pelo Banco de dados. Encontrei vários fóruns com o mesmo problema, e com o uso do `wp cli update` não tem como, pqa hospedagem não aceita acesso ssh. Tudo culpa do cliente! Essa é a horaem que o barato sai caro! Vou deixar ele pagar um pouquinho pelos erros.